# Why didn't Boruto teleport to the animal world?

Tags: naruto, boruto

In one episode, tired of Konohamaru showing off, Boruto steals the summoning scroll and tries to summon a summoning animal, but it doesn't work since he hasn't signed a summoning contract. However, Jiraiya didn't sign a contract and in a flashback in Naruto Shipppudden, he was teleported to Mount Myoboku. Why wasn't Boruto teleported to an Animal world?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The episode you are referring to when Jiraya was teleported to Mount Myōboku, [Tales of a Gutsy Ninja ~Jiraiya Ninja Scroll~ Part 1](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Tales_of_a_Gutsy_Ninja_~Jiraiya_Ninja_Scroll~_Part_1) is actually a filler episode, so I'm not sure if teleporting to the animal's home after performing the [Summoning Technique](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Summoning_Technique) without a blood contract should be considered canon.

> In the anime, it was shown that if a user attempts to summon an animal without first signing a contract, the user will be teleported to the home of the animal they have a natural affinity for

On the other side, nothing happened when Boruto performed the Summoning Technique because, not only did he not have a blood contract, he also did not use the hand signs required to perform a summon

> However in Boruto's case, he neither used a blood sacrifice nor did the necessary hand seals.

Without the hand signs or blood sacrifice, Boruto just kind of slapped his hand on the ground.

Comment: what about when Naruto went to mount Myoboku?

Comment: @Henjin Naruto signed a blood contract when training with Jiraiya in the original series. Him being teleport to [Mount Myoboku](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Mount_Myōboku) and then back to Konoha was through Reverse Summoning Justu. *If they have a summoning contract, they can let the toad use the Reverse Summoning Technique*